# Delete mysql row where date equals expiry date

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-delete

What's the best way to run a mysql query to delete a row if it equals the date in the expire column?

This is my current code:

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM table WHERE DATE(expire) = CURDATE()";

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
// Bind the params to the placeholders
$q->execute();
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Your query looks ok just remove the *. `DELETE FROM table WHERE DATE(expire) = CURDATE()`

Comment: Try the query into MySql first and then inject it into your PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE expire < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

EDIT: As Greg said, I don't really see anything wrong with your current code.  The code I provided might be a little more of a guarantee that your table is properly cleaned up.

Comment: thankyou for your reply but i get this error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM table WHERE DATE(expire) = CURDATE()' at line 1' in /home/stude295/public_html/deletead.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/stude295/public_html/deletead.php(9): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/stude295/public_html/deletead.php on line 9"

Comment: Get rid of the *.  It should be "DELETE FROM table ...".  Not "DELETE * FROM table ..."

Comment: yeh, i am using the query "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE expire < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: Are you getting an error with that?  The error you posted previously shows that you were using a * still.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE expire < curDate()
```

Make sure you named the correct table and the correct fields..